# Android: During alarm - if user locks screen or goes to home screen - how to bring it back again?

Tags: android, android-alarms, onpause

so I am facing small bit of so to call - exploit/bug.
I have an app which triggers activity and wakes up phone from lockscreen and shows alarm, all works fine sound works but there are few scenarios in which I have problem:
If user clicks home button it just minimizes app and thats it, it remains running in background.
If user locks screen, the alarm is silenced - if unlocked within 10 seconds it continues, if unlocked after 10 seconds it's minimized and runs in background.

How would I go about fixing these? what approach would you suggest?
I assume alarm activity goes into onPause?
if so I was thinking of making new Handler and wake up phone in 10 seconds in onPause method but wondering if there is any better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think `post a Handler` is a good idea, there is no grantee that your `Activity` dos not get `destroyed` by Android system, and then you `Handler` will not work.

I suggest to set a new `Alarm` (after 10 seconds) that run a `Service/Broadcast` in `onPause()`, you can send the time of setting the `Alarm` in the `PindingIntent`. get that time check it or cancel the `Alarm`.

Comment: So create new alarm for 10 seconds in OnPause method 
Then if activity is started before that - cancel alarm in OnResume method? is that how you mean?

Apparently I thought Handler is running even when activity is destroyed, I kind of imagined it stacks task in queue of android itself, I tried that way using Handler but ended up having handler acting weird.

Comment: Yes, thats correct cancel the alarm on onResume(). Im not sure how the Handler will act after activity get destroyed.

Comment: Got it working, however it appears even after I kill activity the alarm gets scheduled. Is onPause called together with onStop?

Comment: onStop() called after onPuse(), but there is no grantee that onStop() will be called in case of killing the activity